# weird mouse coordinates on site

Tags: javascript, mousemove

I've added logging of mouse move events on my site, just tracking any mousemove X and Y:

```
window.onmousemove=function(e){
   mouseMoves.push(e.x)
   mouseMoves.push(e.y)
   );
}
```

I do this relative to the window element, or the document for old IE browsers. It seems to be working well, except occasionally I will see  coordinates where the Y value will be very high - 3500 for example.

How is that even possible? are there screens out there that can show 3500 pixels of my site, or does the user somehow move his mouse to a part of the screen that's not visible.. or are these bots?

I'd appreciate any insight into how this is happening..

Comment: can you distinguish whether these events come from window's event listener or from older IE browsers with document's event listener? There may be something fishy going on IE. 

And one guess is that it's 4K screen turned into portrait mode.

Comment: Maybe: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/4K_resolution ?

Comment: @zvona - judging by the user agent some are IE but many are also firefox 38, so I guess it does not explain it entirely. And as for 4K screens - they are pretty rare, no? who browses like that?

Comment: and some even go beyond 4k BTW.